# Python - Lotus Notes (Sending Email)

Tags: python-2.7, lotus-notes

I am trying to use Python 2.7.3.2 to send an email through Lotus Notes 8.5.

There are plenty of examples on how to do this in other languages, and I've done it myself in VBA, but having difficulties with Python.

```
self.db = self.session.getDatabase(server, dbfile)
# ...
mailDoc         = self.db.CreateDocument
mailDoc.Form    = "Memo"
mailDoc.sendto  = recipientList
mailDoc.subject = subject
mailDoc.Body    = bodytext
```

Error returned: `AttributeError: Property 'CreateDocument.Form' can not be set.`

I have attempted to skip setting the form, but it also fails on setting any of these attributes.

Would anyone have code on this, or suggestions on what to try to resolve it.

Comment: can you share code you used for VBA?

Comment: @francisco-jurado sure. https://gist.github.com/codorizzi/8da8b28562a50789150e9f1591e14cda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about Python, but my guess is that the shorthand notation `document.item = "foo"` for setting an item value is not supported.  Most likely, you need to do this:

```
mailDoc.AppendItemValue("Form","Memo")
```

(You can also use ReplaceItemValue, which is equivalent for a newly created document, and also works for updating existing documents, so many people prefer to just remember the one method name.)

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks! Used mailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo").

Comment: Glad it helped, particularly since I had initially left off the itemName argument from my sample call.